# visualize a tap on view , show tap indicator

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, avfoundation

I'm trying to add tap to focus onto my custom camera View and i managed to do that but now i need to show something so the user can know he is actually doing something .... show a UI like Apple's yellow square , or SnapChat's white circle. a custom indicator...

## Here is my code:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let screenSize = view.bounds.size
        if let touchPoint = touches.first {
            let x = touchPoint.location(in: view).y / screenSize.height
            let y = 1.0 - touchPoint.location(in: view).x / screenSize.width
            let focusPoint = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
            
            if let device = captureDevice {
                do {
                    try device.lockForConfiguration()
                    
                    device.focusPointOfInterest = focusPoint
                    //device.focusMode = .continuousAutoFocus
                    device.focusMode = .autoFocus
                    //device.focusMode = .locked
                    device.exposurePointOfInterest = focusPoint
                    device.exposureMode = AVCaptureExposureMode.continuousAutoExposure
                    device.unlockForConfiguration()
                }
                catch {
                    // just ignore
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

now how can i add a custom indicator on that tap to focus? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add an overlay view on top of the rest of the screen. You can then draw your indicator in its draw() function. Whenever you need the overlay display to update call its setNeedsDisplay() function. In the example below I have included that in the set function the touchPoint. Make sure you disable user interaction on this view though otherwise your touches won't get through the underlying user interface.

```
class OverlayView : UIView {

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        // draw your touch indicator here
        if let pt = _touchPoint {
            let color:UIColor = UIColor.gray
            let rect = CGRect(x:pt.x - 30, y:pt.y - 30, width:60, height:60)
            let bpath:UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(rect: rect)

            color.set()
            bpath.stroke()
        }
    }

    private var _touchPoint : CGPoint?
    var touchPoint : CGPoint? {
        set(value) {
            _touchPoint = value
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
        get {
            return _touchPoint
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: So if i will add an image in the draw func it will be seen ?

Comment: I have extended the example code to show how you would draw a square about a variable touch point in the overlay view.